# Extend encrypted message with AES 128 mbedtls

Tags: c++, c, encryption, aes

I'm trying to extend the encrypted message with mbedtls/aes.h

This is my code:

```
void encrypt(char * plainText, char * key, unsigned char * outputBuffer){
 
  mbedtls_aes_context aes;
 
  mbedtls_aes_init( &aes );
  mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc( &aes, (const unsigned char*) key, strlen(key) * 8 );
  mbedtls_aes_crypt_ecb( &aes, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, (const unsigned char*)plainText, outputBuffer);
  mbedtls_aes_free( &aes );
}
 
void decrypt(unsigned char * chipherText, char * key, unsigned char * outputBuffer){
 
  mbedtls_aes_context aes;
 
  mbedtls_aes_init( &aes );
  mbedtls_aes_setkey_dec( &aes, (const unsigned char*) key, strlen(key) * 8 );
  mbedtls_aes_crypt_ecb(&aes, MBEDTLS_AES_DECRYPT, (const unsigned char*)chipherText, outputBuffer);
  mbedtls_aes_free( &aes );
}
 
void test() {
 

 
  char * key = "Yq3t6w9z$C&F)J@M";
 
  char *plainText = "Message Message Message Message Message Message Message Message Message Message Message ";
  unsigned char cipherTextOutput[16];
  unsigned char decipheredTextOutput[16];
 
  encrypt(plainText, key, cipherTextOutput);
  decrypt(cipherTextOutput, key, decipheredTextOutput);
 
  Serial.println("\nPlain text:");
  Serial.println(plainText);
 
  Serial.println("\nCiphered text:");
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
 
    char str[3];
 
    sprintf(str, "%02x", (int)cipherTextOutput[i]);
    Serial.print(str);
  }
 
  Serial.println("\n\nDeciphered text:");
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)decipheredTextOutput[i]);
  }
}
```

And this is the output:

Plain text:

```
Message Message Message Message Message Message Message Message Message Message Message
```

Ciphered text:

```
cb91d2da0d1be520239651f63b259be8
```

Deciphered text:

```
Message Message
```

I wanna encrypt bigger texts, how can I extend the buffer?

Comment: You have a hard-coded length of 16 up there.

Comment: I already tried to change the values, but after changing it i get a deciphered result like �␀␟�?`␟�?

Comment: mbedtls_aes_crypt_ecb(..) only encrypts  one block (16 bytes). You need to loop over your message and encrypt it 16 bytes at a time ...

Answer (score 1):

`mbedtls_aes_crypt_ecb` will only encrypt a single block (exactly 16 bytes) of data.

If you want to encrypt / decrypt a larger amount of data you can use one of the other `mbedtls_aes_crypt_*` functions, e.g. `mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc`.

Example:

```cpp
void encrypt(char* key, unsigned char* iv, int length, char* plainText, unsigned char* outputBuffer){
  mbedtls_aes_context aes;
  mbedtls_aes_init(&aes);
  mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc(&aes, (const unsigned char*)key, strlen(key)*8);
  mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc(&aes, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, length, iv, (const unsigned char*)plainText, outputBuffer);
  mbedtls_aes_free(&aes);
}

void decrypt(char* key, unsigned char* iv, int length, unsigned char* chipherText, unsigned char* outputBuffer){
  mbedtls_aes_context aes;
  mbedtls_aes_init(&aes);
  mbedtls_aes_setkey_dec(&aes, (const unsigned char*)key, strlen(key)*8);
  mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc(&aes, MBEDTLS_AES_DECRYPT, length, iv, (const unsigned char*)chipherText, outputBuffer);
  mbedtls_aes_free(&aes);
}
```

- `iv` needs to be a 16-byte large buffer with the initialization value (needs to be the same for encrypt & decrypt)
  If you don't want to bother with this you can just provide 16 bytes of zeroes for this.
  (`mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc` will write into this while encrypting / decrypting)
- `length` needs to be the number of bytes you want to encode / decode (must be a multiple of 16)

Example:

```cpp
const char* message = "Message Message Message Message Message Message Message Message\0";

// encrypt
unsigned char encryped[64];
unsigned char enc_iv[16] = {0};
encrypt("Yq3t6w9z$C&F)J@M", enc_iv, 64, message, encrypted);

// decrypt
unsigned char result[64];
unsigned char dec_iv[16] = {0};
decrypt("Yq3t6w9z$C&F)J@M", dec_iv, 64, encrypted, result);

Serial.print(result)
```

If you want you can also take a look at the [different modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) that are available & pick whats best for your use-case.

`ECB` is rather insecure, since it encrypts each block individually, so patterns between different blocks are preserved in the cyper-text.

I would recommend to use `CBC` / `CFB128` / `CFB8` instead.